# Why compiler doent complain for wait used in non-synchronised block

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

As far as I know when we want to call `wait` in java, we need to synchronize API/block else it will end up in `IllegalMonitorStateException` at run time. My question is, as we are so sure its always result in exception, why compiler doesn't complain about it?

Comment: Because it can't know. You may have entered a synchronized block somewhere up in the call stack, making it completely legal to call `wait()`.

Comment: @vanza Hmm, 'checked synchronization'? *-runs away-*

Comment: @vanza There are static code analyzers which are analyzing the code flow, like [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/): [MWN: Mismatched wait() (MWN_MISMATCHED_WAIT)](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#MWN_MISMATCHED_WAIT)

Comment: `Object o1 = this; Object o2 = this; synchronized(o1) {o2.wait();}` - legal or not? What about `Object o1 = this.longAndComplicatedMethodCall(); synchronized(o1) {this.wait();}`? What about `synchronized(staticHashMap.get(this.ID)) {this.wait();}`?

Comment: In such cases, I'd add some documentation stating that the code must be called within an (outer) sync block. e.g. `assert Thread.holdsLock( o1 ); o1.wait(); `

Comment: Apart from the fact there is no way the compiler could know, you have the problem that the compiler doesn't have a special understanding of how any of the libraries work (Unless they are mentioned in the JLS) so that even if it could know, it wouldn't do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you may have been calling the method that has `wait` in a synchronised block somewhere higher up in the call stack. Compiler can find only the syntactic validity of your code - it can't check for logical errors.

Comment: Of course it can check for logical errors. Where do you think the type system comes from etc?

Comment: Hmm... our definitions of logical errors differ I guess :).

Comment: @mvd It can't detect this one. A compiler can check for *some* logical errors, and the type system is a good example how far it can go. The range of logical errors it can detect is described as the 'static semantics ' of the language. This semantic isn't static.

Comment: As far as I can see this is nothing but the halting problem in new cloths.

Comment: "Compiler can find only the syntactic validity of your code" Compilers check for use of uninitialized variables and unreachable code. According to your definition, is that part of "syntactic validity"?

Comment: @AndreasVeithen you are right, so is other commenters. But within the context of this QA, I feel it is OK to be less-correct.

Answer (score 1):

No compiler could detect this error. It isn't a static semantic of the language. It isn't a semantic of the language at all, actually, it is a semantic of the runtime library.

Answer (score 1):

As [KDM mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32304072/3182664): The synchronization might have taken place somewhere higher in the call stack. And as an intuitive example for a case where it simply is *not possible* to detect whether the call is legal or not:

```
class Example
{
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    private void run() throws InterruptedException
    {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5)
        {
            synchronized (lock)
            {
                doWait();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            doWait();
        }
    }

    private void doWait() throws InterruptedException
    {
        lock.wait();
    }

}
```

You simply do not know whether the call happens from inside the `synchronized` block or not.

Answer (score 0):

`wait()` is part of object class, hence we can call it directly. In threads, there is nothing similar to throws clause to indicate compiler that method should be surrounded by synchronized block.